# How run formulas in VBA without getting Run-time error 9?

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I am trying to run the following VBA script:

```
Sub FillTable()

Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("E5").Select
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("E5").Formula = "XLOOKUP(B1,'Cleaned & Scored Data'!B2:B9,'Cleaned & Scored Data'!E2:E9)/XLOOKUP(B1,'Cleaned & Scored Data'!$B$2:$B$9,'Cleaned & Scored Data'!D2:D9)"

End Sub
```

And I am getting

> "Run-time error 9: Subscript out of range".

It's been a while since I've used VBA. Can anyone jog my memory on what I am doing wrong? Thanks!!

I was expecting Cell E5 on Sheet3 to be filled with the results of the formula, but instead got the error.

Comment: The `ActiveWorkbook` has no worksheet named "Sheet3".